# Regular expressions: search (instead of match) with DFA

Tags: regex

I have been wondering about theory behind search mode of regex matcher. So, say I have a regex that matches `aab`, what if instead of `match` at the beginning of the string I wanna be able to perform this match starting from any position of the string. What I mean - in match mode I can only verify that string `aab` is consistent with a regex, on the other hand with `search` this should work with say `aaab` producing corresponding span result.
So super specifically - is there any way to build DFA `searcher`, or this is fundamentally impossible since it would require additional memory which you cant have in DFSM. It is obvious though that you can in fact build `searcher` from `matcher` by reapplying `matcher` to input string in a for loop, but complexity of such approach is something like O(len_of_pattern * len_of_input).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you basically answered your own question. Search, like many other features in modern regex implementations, leverages the wonder of memory to do things unfeasible with a Finite Automata. DFAs traditionally cannot loop over strings or backtrack along input as this would require memory. Search requires the ability to find a match and then understand how that match fits in the string.

Answer (score 2):

A regex searcher is basically the same thing as a regex matcher with `.*` tacked onto the front of the expression.